# Mathsymbol in the documentclass memoir

Tags: amsmath

I write a thesis with `\documentclass{memoir}` and included the ams packages by

```
usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs,datetime}
```

However there is the difference in using bolt math sign. Here is the way I would like to have it

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
 Here are some words

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{S}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and here is some code how it is displayed in the memoir class

```
  \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{memoir}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
       \begin{document}
    Here are some words
    \begin{equation}
    \mathbb{S}
    \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

and here is the output

[image]

How can I get the same mathbb symbol in the second code as in the first one?

Comment: `mathpazo` is changing the black board font. Remove it if you want AMS black board fonts.

Comment: do not use the `OT1` encoding, use `T1`

Comment: As others have mentioned, `mathpazo` and `amssymb` both provide `bb` fonts, so the load order matters. BTW: this question has nothing to do with `memoir`

Comment: @daleif I will retag my question. Is there a way that math-code is displayed using the amssymb?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by *math-code*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to revert the setting made by `mathpazo` with respect to `\mathbb`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}

\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}}

\begin{document}
Here are some words $\mathbb{S}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks egreg! That's was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Hum... very interesting. We can use any other font for `\mathbb`! I tested `cmss`. But suppose that I want to use `cmtt` for the normal math font. How to do this? I tried your code together `\mathrm` but no success.

Comment: @Sigur That's much more complicated. Look at `fntguide.pdf`